# Considering languages evolved over time, what could be the initial dataset?

Tags: evolutionary-linguistics, origin-of-language

If I assume evolution of language took place over time, I am curious as to what can be the initial population of words or syllable or anything.

Lets say I am about to write a algorithm to evolve certain language. How do I start with it?
What can the inital data set?

Comment: Can you define "evolution" in the context of your question? I'm not sure if linguists use that term with the same meaning you are intending.

Comment: There are many approaches on [Simulated evolution of languages](http://www.google.com/search?q=language+evolution+simulation). Each of them has its own (1) initial data set; (2) evolution rules, like branching, reduction, complication, adoption, and many others; (3) extinction criteria; (4) random events. I believe you have to choose an entire set of these four. And, certainly, read the existing works on the topic.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a computational linguistics question or a "philosophical" question. Please clarify it and add the appropriate tag if the former is true.